# Convert vector of objects to vector of pointers

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have some set of classes: Object, AnotherObject, OtherObject, etc. Also I have some legacy code. Something like this:

```
std::vector<Object> getObjectsFromSomeSource();
std::vector<AnotherObject> getAnotherObjectsFromSomeSource();
std::vector<OtherObject> getOtherObjectsFromSomeSource();
...
```

I refactored this set of classes, now they have the same interface. Now I need to create class that works with vector of pointers to the interface. The question is can I do it this way (is this code is correct? Are there any pitfalls in code? Maybe, you could offer a better solution):

```
class ObjectContainer
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IObject>> m_objectVec;
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IObject> > objectVec() const;
    void setObjectVec(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IObject> > &objectVec);

    template <typename T>
    void setObjectVec(const std::vector<T>& objectVec)
    {
        for (const T& item: objectVec)
        {
            m_objectVec.push_back(std::make_shared<T>(item));
        }
    }
};
```

This code seems irrational and ineffective, but I don't know how to do it without rewriting of legacy functions.

Comment: not sure if I understand what you are doing, but why not keep the old vectors containing objects and write an adaptor that allows to get/set elements as shared pointers? That copy you make there seems like an unnecesssary overhead

Comment: @user463035818 I want to work with the same interface, but there is too many functions that return vector of objects (not pointers), so I need to rewrite this function set, but don't want to. Of course, there is unnecesssary overhead, but this is not critical in my case

Comment: what i tried to suggest is to not rewrite those functions that return a vector of objects, but just to wrap them into something that provides you access to the objects via shared pointers of your polymorphic type.

Comment: Do you get the vectors of objects from your legacy code?

Comment: @super yes, I do

Comment: @user463035818 in this case I need to write new method to get objects from database or copy objects in wrapper. I don't want to do it because of worktime overhead

Comment: Have you considered using std::variant ? for example std::vector< std::variant<Object,AnotherObject, OtherObject> > having a common base can ease the work with the variant if i recall correctly..

Comment: If the overhead of copying all the object is not a problem for you, I don't see any issues with your approach.

Comment: note that you do a copy here, and not referencing the objects from your legacy vectors. you also might want to check out `std::transform` when converting stl containers, if your prefer using <algorithm> tools.

Comment: If you don't need to mix the objects and don't want copy then with the variant approach you could try: `std::variant< std::vector<Object>&, std::vector<AnotherObject>& >`